# Setting express to use the querystring parser does not work as intended

Tags: node.js, express

I don't need, or want, the additional functionality of the qs parser in my express application.

For the following issue I am using the query `?State[]=alabama`

When I use `app.set('query parser', 'simple');` and `console.log(req.query)` I am shown `[Object: null prototype] { 'State[]': 'alabama' }`.

If I use `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` instead of the above `app.set(...)`, express *still* seems to use the qs module, returning `{ State: [ 'alabama' ] }`.

My question is why am I seeing the `[Object: null prototype]` when using `app.set('query parser', 'simple');` and why does `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` not remove the qs modules functionality?

the rest of my application config looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
const cors = require('cors');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/api');
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express();

//Problematic config
// app.set('query parser', 'simple');
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
/* eslint-enable no-unused-v.ars */

app.engine('.hbs', engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
  }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));

... db connection, routes etc.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Using the simple parser makes thing's easier right now.

I've read the docs: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded, and https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.settings.table for query parsing. Looked at stack overflow and a blog. I can't find a duplicate of this problem. And obviously I've tried debugging myself.